# View Incoming sms in Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is there any way to view an incoming message on twilio number ?
I know there is a response mechanism which is send reply to an incoming message, but I want to get the incoming sms content

Comment: Where do you want to get it? Forwarded to your cell phone, forwarded to an email address, saved to a database,...? You can see all received messages in Twilio Console.

Comment: I just need to show it a dashboard

Comment: Check out my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210368/how-can-i-best-manually-reply-to-texts-from-a-twilio-phone-number/63236358#63236358